# What am I doing wrong with TailwindCSS? My menus keep being popped open?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I'm completely stuck... I'm amazed by the kit in TailWindCSS and trying to implement it.

I have copied in the ecommerce template as you see here: https://pastebin.com/0Exxu31S

I've used the input CSS of:
`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

`

But every time I try to load the page, it comes on with the menu open and without the mouseover functionality is working. I'm a bit lost. Can anyone give me a pointer in the rigth direction?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

I have already tried documentation, search stackoverflow but I can't make sense of it. I'm good old fashin stuck! :O

Comment: And yes, I have already run this successfully
`
jh@Janniks-MacBook-Pro-6 tailwind_test % npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch


Rebuilding...

Done in 334ms.
`

Comment: It doesn't look like you have anything that changes the states of your nav-bar items. I'm pretty sure they give you all the relevant styles. If you want to close and open the menus, you need to add some functions/event listeners. Can you show us the link to the site you took the component from?

Comment: Hi @ChenBr
Thank you so much for taking the time to look at it. 

I've used this: https://tailwindui.com/components/ecommerce/page-examples/product-pages

As a navigation, I've used this: https://tailwindui.com/components/ecommerce/components/store-navigation
The one called: "With simple menu and promo" for an example. 

And then you can see what happens here: https://app.screencast.com/xlwL5ngzzTUuw

Thank you 

Comment: Did you add any Javascript to the `Store Navigation`? It looks like this component needs scripts to work (either `Vue` or `React`). Did you notice it? This is the missing functionality, which is why the navigation is always open. Nothing closes or manages it. The script is located on the right side of the page, next to `Preview` and `Code`.